# Generalizng the Babylonian Square Root Algorithm to nth roots

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been looking for root algorithms, and came across the Babylonian Algorithm. I really like it since it is simple and easy to understand. But the problem is that it only takes square roots, when I am making a function that can take the root of a number with any power. I am just trying it take take positive integer.

Here is the function:

```
double functions::rot(double x, double y) {
    double z = x;
    double w = 1;
    double e = 0.000001; 
    while (z - w > e){
        z = (z + w) / 2;
        w = x / z;
    }
    return z;
}
```

y is the power. Does anyone have a way to change this algorithm so y is the power of the root? For example, if y = 3, it takes the cubed root.

Comment: Try changing `w = x/z` to `w=x/(z*z)`, what will you get?

Comment: The graphical interpretation of the Babylonian method is adjusting the lengths of the sides of a rectangle until you get a square, while preserving the given area. You can easily abstract it to higher dimensions by fiddling with length of one of the edges of cube, hypercube etc. and adjusting the other edges (at once) to make it closer to the actual figure.

Comment: changing` w = x/z` to `w = x/(z*z)` gives me 3.812388 when x = 64.

Comment: Sorry, should have also change `z - w > e` to `std::abs(z-w) > e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment that says to change `w = x / z` to `w = x / z*z` is only `1/3` (pun intended) correct. You also need two more changes, which I think are obvious from this Python code:

```
def rot(x, y): # 
    z = x
    w = 1
    e = 0.000001
    while (z - w > e):
        z = ((y - 1) * z + w) / y
        w = x / (z ** (y - 1)) # a ** b is a to the power of b in Python
                               # you might want to use modular exponentiation in C++
                               # (or not if y is double...)
    return z


print(rot(64, 3)) # prints 4
print(rot(59, 6)) # prints 1.9730678338673044
```

See here for a [reference](http://www.rowan.edu/open/depts/math/osler/Babylon.pdf). I suggest you read it, as it gives more in depth explanations.

Comment: FYI reference link is broken. Here is a new location for the reference: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237415858_EXTENDING_THE_BABYLONIAN_ALGORITHM

Answer (score 0):

Newton's method is similar to the Babylonian method and can be used to extract roots of any power. We assume both *k*, the root, and *n*, the input, are positive integers; both divisions in the assignment of *u* are integer division (ignore the remainder):

```
function iroot(k, n)
    k1, u, s := k-1, n, n+1
    while u < s
        u := (u * k1 + n / (u ** k1)) / k
        s := u
    return s
```

Warning: untested pseudocode. Function `iroot` returns the largest integer that does not exceed *n* when multiplied by itself *k* times.

Comment: Although this algorithm looks nice, I need it to take and return doubles, since I won't just be using whole numbers for the input. The root is to be whole positive number though.

Comment: Do you really need `double`s, in the sense of real numbers, or are fractionals sufficient? Then you could first (or afterwards) take the respective power of the number. Example `x` = `n^(2/3)` = `root(n^2, 3)` = `root(n,3)^2`